# Retrieve version number from another exe

Tags: vb.net

I want to write another app's version number to my label.

With this code I can get the version of my app:

```
Label1.Text = My.Application.Info.Version.ToString
```

But what should I do to get it from another application? Is it even possible?

The path of the app I want to retrieve the version number:

```
Application.StartupPath & "\..\hello.exe"
```

Comment: Try replacing `Return Version.Parse(...)` with `Return System.Version.Parse(...)` in the answer's code. The error occurs because you have a `Label` called `Version`, but the function tries to use the [**`System.Version` class**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.version(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Thanks! Errors are gone. How can I redirect version to a label? I can not see any changes. (I'm newby, maybe I might have missed something)

Comment: Okay, I got it! Thanks @VisualVincent

Comment: @Plutonix how can I mark this question as resolved?

Comment: No need to being a dupe does that for us.  When you get enough reputation, the right thing to do is to upvote the answer on the dupe if/when it works.